# Opening a Separate ViewController with back button from a tabbar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Tabbar controller and in that controller I am showing more then 5 viewcontroller. everything is working as expected.

But now I have a ViewController that has UiTableView, On the cell click I want to open a DetailView Controller.

That DetailViewController will be Having a Title in the Navigation View Controller and the backbutton to go back again to list.

Please help me how to do it using Swift?

Comment: **now I have a ViewController that has UiTableView** this one from the tabs ??

Comment: yes. that is from tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func moveToNexScreen(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nextVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as! NextViewController
    let navigationVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextVc)
    present(navigationVc, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
}

class NextViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(self.closeBackButtonPressed))        
}

@objc func closeBackButtonPressed(){
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Put your detailView inside `UINavigationController(rootViewController: detailVc)` and then you can present it and to have a back button you can add a barbutton item on the detailsView programatically

Comment: I did as you said, but when I click on the backbutton it takes me to the blank screen but not the ViewController that contains the TableView

Comment: What method are you using from didSelectRowAtIndexPath, pushNavigationController or self.present, if you are using push then it may not work so you need to present but that will not have a backbutton so you need to create a barbutton item in your detail view in view did load like self.navigationController.leftBarButtonItem.

Comment: I ended up using stand alone NavigationBar. and making buttons on it

Comment: Try my updated answer put two view controllers in a tabar and from any one of the view controller use create navigation bar like I have done and to the destination view controller add next view controller code if you are not able to do I will provide you with a git link with sample project. Thanks

Comment: though I have done without using Navigation controller. I used Navigation bar, but For back button I have already done what you suggested here

Answer (score 3):

The vc you want to show the detailVC from should be embedded inside a navigationController , then use push/pop to manage show/hide

```
let vc = ///

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

//

self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: I have done this, I embeded it into the Navigation controller and pushed it into Navigation controller, when it gets open, there is back button. but from that backbutton it goes to blank screen not the UItableView screen that exist into the taabbar. or which opened the DetailView vc

Answer (score 0):

USE -

```
#import <DetailViewController.h>

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    DetailViewController *details = (DetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

    details.dictionary = _json[indexPath.row]; // to pass data

}
```

In Storyboard -

```
Select Cell and drag a segue to Details view controller
```

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this storyboard illustration will help you. It's clean to show the vcs you need. [image]

Comment: This picture is little wrong or you can say this is not what I want , according to my requirements, I want to ask, suppose that there is a simple view controller just before the Navigation controller, and that ViewController whishes to open the Navigation controller or the RootView Controller.  but On this Root view controller I want to have a back button that goes back to simple view controller. which is the first Item of the Tab bar

Comment: why not just use nav viewcontroller as the firstItem of a tab bar?

Comment: bcz I have whole application built in that way